# Symfony unique fields in entity by format

Tags: php, symfony

For my logic I need generate uniq invite code by some format - three digits and two letters. Before I use `Ramsey uuid` but for users this is very complicated invite code for remember by heart. What correct way for automatic generate invite code by some format, example - `A123B`  ?

I have entity user with uniq field, `inviteCode`. And when I create new entity I want generate automatic uniq random code by format - `three digits and two letters`

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @AssertBridge\UniqueEntity(
 *     groups={"registration"},
 *     fields="inviteCode",
  *     errorPath="not valid",
 *     message="This inviteCode is already in use."
 * )
 */
 class User extends AbstractUser implements UserInterface
 {
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=500, unique=true)
 * @Annotation\SerializedName("_invite_code")
 */
private $inviteCode;
```

I found something like that

```
    private function calculateReference($number)
{
    $multipliers = array(7,3,1);
    $length = strlen($number);
    $numberArr = str_split($number);

    $sum = 0;

    for ($i = $length - 1; $i >= 0; --$i)
    {
        $sum += $numberArr[$i] * $multipliers[($length - 1 - $i) % 3];
    }

    return $number.(10 - $sum % 10) % 10;
}
```

first get max id from table then call function `calculateReference` with id, but I need regulate length, example only 6 symbol

What good way you now for generate some hash by format `three digits and two letters` ?

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I simply do this in the controller, like this:

```
$genActivationHash = bin2hex(random_bytes(64));
$activationLink = $this->container->getParameter('base_url') . 
"/activate/" . $genActivationHash;
```

You can edit the length of the hash, by simply changing the number of bytes

> random_bytes(n)

Edit; I see now, that it does not satisfy your requirement for two letters and three digits.

Comment: It's true, not satisfy, need format two letters and three digits